# Fabric goes crazy?

Tags: procedural

I just tried to reproduce a [tutorial to create a procedural fabric fiber](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CoCDbCbeiAk) and I think I almost got it except that sometimes the fiber doesn't behave as supposed to... 
[image: Screenshot]
See, the first two rows look good but then only one in too is good...
If someone is nice enough to watch the video and maybe help me find out what's wrong I would really appreciate it !

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Hi. I think ideally this question should go to the creator of the tutorial. It's a pretty tough ask to want someone to watch the entire tutorial for you. My suggestion is to watch the tutorial again and try and work out where you went wrong.

Comment: Yes you are right, I was just wondering if it may be obvious to anyone